# UIBarButtonItem hide element and space that it takes

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

How could i hide `UIBarButtonItem` and space that it takes?

For hiding i use this code:

```
searchButton.isEnabled = false
searchButton.tintColor = UIColor.clear
```

But it still uses the space and if i have a third element it looks like a gap between them.
Changing width does not solve my problem.

```
searchButton.width = 0.0
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that i found was `searchButton.customView = UIView()`

Answer (score 1):

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems Is an optional array of buttons on the right in the navigation bar. You go through it and remove a button from it.

Comment: for some reason `rightBarButtonItems` returns nil as well as `rightBarButtonItem`. Any idea why?

Comment: I guess the problem is that i do not have this VC in a navigation controller that is why your solution would not work

Comment: It’s the same concept with whatever you are doing. All those buttons you have on top must be in some sort of an array, no? 

If not, then show how you create them and show them on top.